# get back to Ropsten: reclaim address after deletion of genesis block & /testnet/geth/chaindata

Tags: genesis, quorum, goethe, chaindata

Recently I've been playing around with JPM's [Quorum](https://medium.com/@s.matthew.english/jpm-quorum-0-3-what-is-constellation-ed00f52b7e59).

It's similar to `go-ethereum` (`goethe`) in many ways, *but* one of the key differentiating factors is that it has a genesis block which isn't the same as the normal network, and I suppose, by extension, the "normal" test-network (Ropsten revivial).

My guess is that running Quorum from my machine has overwritten the genesis block of my standard Ethereum network, in addition to the standard testnets.

To get myself back to Ropsten I deleted the following directory:

```
database=/Users/s.matthew.english/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata
```

However, later when I looked at the balance for my account, I was startled to see this:

[image]

The block numbers are also strange:

[image]

Seems that I'm just running my own private network with myself, is that the case?

My account, `0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6`, is visible on Etherscan as it was before:

[image]

What is the best way to get myself back onto Ropsten revival, with possession of my keys? Is it still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, from [If you need some Ropsten Testnet ethers...](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/61zdn8/if_you_need_some_ropsten_testnet_ethers/):

```
geth --testnet removedb
geth --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

Comment: yes! works :) thank you. do you know how I could avoid this situation in the future?

Comment: Try using the `--datadir` parameter to specify a different directory for your different environments.